# How to return variable from actionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing

I'm not looking for direct answers. Just a general direction where I'm supposed to search or little hints, as this is an assignment for a class.

I am supposed to create a game, and in order for the user to start the game, they must enter their name through a JOPtionPane, at the moment, I have coded this:

```
JButton nameBtn = new JButton("NAME");
    nameBtn.setBounds(25, 10, 250, 30);     
    nameBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String name;
            do{
                name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "ENTER YOUR NAME", "", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                if(name != null)
                    ;
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "No name entered");
            }while(name == null);
        }   
    });
```

What I want to do is then display that user entered name unto another panel. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: There are potentially multiple solutions to getting a value out of a functional interface implementation like this, but which one will depend on what exactly you want to do with the `name` input. What do you plan on doing with it?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, then you want to use the `name` result from the input dialog and display it in an existing label in the outer class. You can simply create a method in the outer class that takes the name as a String argument and that adds it to any of the components in that outer class. You can call this method from within the `ActionListener`. Without including the element where the name should end up in your question, I cannot go more specific than this.

Comment: Thank you. I've been racking my brain all weekend over this, and I hate how simple the answer is.

Comment: It happens. I'm glad that you've solved the problem. If my answer (or that from anyone else) helped for this, then you can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Execution continues uninterrupted immediate on from the call to `addActionListener`. So the code following the listener registration is executed at the wrong time to receive such a returned value.

The action to be performed should be initiated within the `actionPerformed` method or methods that it calls. And that's about it. In an anonymous inner class, as used in the question, access is available to the enclosing scope.

As a note of style, listener implementations should usually be short, just removing the necessary information from the event (often only that it happened at all) and calling an uncluttered method that does the useful work.

For tasks that may block the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), work can be done on another thread. Any resultant manipulation to AWT/Swing object need then be performed with a `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` call to run on the EDT.

Some methods dealing with modal dialogues, such as presumably `showInputDialog`, use a hack whereby EDT events are processed within the method call. You can see this in stack traces. Modal dialogues are generally considered poor UI.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I found my own answer

```
// buttons
    JButton nameBtn = new JButton("NAME");
    nameBtn.setBounds(25, 10, 250, 30);     
    nameBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String name;
            do{
                name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "ENTER YOUR NAME", "", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                
                if(name != null)
                    ;
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "No name entered");
            }while(name == null);
            
            //take user input (name) and assign it into a JLabel, which will be added
              to my desired Panel
            JLabel userName = new JLabel(name);
            botPan.add(userName);
            userName.setBounds(400, 20, 55, 30);

        }   
    });
```